# fetching html that is actually a number, want to add 1 to it and replace it

Tags: javascript, addition

i'm trying to add 1 to a value that I fetched from my HTML using jquery.

At the moment it is appending 1, treating the value as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You want `parseInt`. You should provide a base argument, as Paolo mentions, for otherwise it may be interpreted as octal if it has a leading `0` (or hex, if it has a leading `0x`).

```
js> parseInt("1", 10)+1
2
js> parseInt("010")
8
js> parseInt("0x10")
16
```

Comment: You should always specify the second argument of parseInt to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with `parseInt`! You should *always* specify the second argument, which is the base:

```
$('div.c2 a').text(
   parseInt($('div.c2 a').text(),10)+1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast a string to number, using the [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_Number.asp) function, it will work whenever the number is a integer or a float:

```
var i = Number(myValue) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested (with jQuery)

```
$('.vote-count-post').each(function() {
  var n = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)+1;
  $(this).text(n);
});
```

This will add one to the element text. In this case, adds one to all votes on this page! (works in firebug - too bad it's only on the page)

Comment: Hahaha, I just put that into a loop and ran it 1000 times. Funny results.

Comment: Highly entertaining first thing in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = parseInt(x)+1 //assuming input in an integer
```

or

```
x = parseFloat(x)+1 //assuming input is non-integer
```

You need to force a type conversion to *integer* from *string*.

Comment: You should always specify the second argument of parseInt to avoid surprises.